# In an EJS template why might a Javascript promise work when written on 1 line, but fail when on 3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

The following line of code searches a mongodb database and returns a promise.  It works as expected when included in app.js.

```
User.findOne({ data: 'random string'}).then().catch();
```

When the same line of code is included in an EJS template it also works as expected.

```
<% User.findOne({ data: 'random string'}).then().catch(); %>
```

However when it is split up on 3 separate lines an in EJS template it throws an error.

```
<% User.findOne({ data: 'random string'}) %> 
<% .then() %>
<% .catch(); %>
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in C:\fileLocation\index.ejs while
>   compiling ejs

**Question:** Why might that be?  Evidently I misunderstand an important piece of EJS mechanics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn’t that it’s on different lines, it’s that it’s in different `<% %>` code blocks. You can’t do that because they’re supposed to be able to have content between them and that makes no sense when the code has to be contiguous. (In this case, they *do* even have content between them: the whitespace.)

One across multiple lines should be fine:

```
<% User.findOne({ data: 'random string' })
    .then()
    .catch(); %>
```

at which point you’ll probably run into the problem of promises being useless in templates. Keeping queries out of them is a good idea in general anyway, though.